# unclear what you're asking vs too broad

Tags: discussion

What's the difference between these 2 concepts ?
They sound to be  the same.

**unclear what you're asking**

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question.

**too broad**

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too
>   long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or
>   to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: "what's the difference" (imagine there's nothing else in the question) => unclear. "List all the possible cases when one should pick too broad over unclear" => too broad. See also: [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/165773) at MSE

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Surely you can understand the difference between a question being unclear and a question being clear but requiring too long an answer?

Comment: @EJP yes, if that's the difference

Comment: So what *else* could it possibly mean?

Comment: @EJP that's the question :)

Answer (score 6):

If I can **definitely** tell that the question asked is too broad, I use too broad. How can you tell a question is too broad? Well, exactly how it says in the description:

1. Answers would be too long for SO.
2. Too many possible answers. (E.g. everybody just suggest their preferred technology).

If I can't tell *whether* either of these would occur, or if the question actually does *not* seem too broad but there's some really confusing part to it, I use unclear.

Comment: this makes things even too broad and unclear , but thank you :)